# Error "expression must have (pointer-to-) function type" C++

Tags: c++

So, I've got this code, and I'm trying to call a method that's been stored into an array which is inside of a structure "Menu", but I'm getting this "expression must have (pointer-to-) function type," error when trying to call the function.

Here's my array, it's initialized later, if that part's needed, please let me know.

```
void(       Menu::*_Opt_Function[MAX_SUB][MAX_OPT])(int);
```

And here is calling the function, within the structure, where the error is occurring.

```
void CallFunction()
    {
        ((void(Menu::*)(int))_Opt_Function[CurrentMenu][Current_Opt[CurrentMenu]])(0);
    }
```

Comment: In order to call a method, you need an object to call it on. This is true whether you call it directly by name, or indirectly via a pointer-to-member. So, do you have an object of type `Menu` handy?

Comment: It's illegal for user-written code to use identifiers of the form _Capital. They are reserved for use by the implementation.

Comment: Why are you casting the function if it is already defined as the proper type?

Comment: @Puppy Only in the global scope.